# How to align form and text generated by function?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm developing a webpage that has many forms with some text close to form. This form and text are generated by a function, but I get this

[image]

As you can see the forms and the text are not aligned with forms and text below. I would like to have this:

[image]

(this work because I put spaces manually). This is how I create forms.

```
function add_form($product,$name,$productp)
{
  $productpt = "X";

  echo $name;
  echo '<input type="text" name="'. $product. '" id="'. $product. '" style="font-size:12pt;height:30px"/> x'.$productp. '€
  price:'.$productpt.'€<br>';
}

echo '<form  method="post" name="form1" id="form1" autocomplete="off">'; //start form    
echo '<div class="leftpane">'; //start leftpane
echo '<h1>';

echo '<font size="6" color="red"> ALIMENTS </font><br>';

//ADD ELEMENTS IN MY MENU
//The first argument is the form name and id, the second is the name that will be printed(to the left of the form), the third argument is the price.
$menu[] = new Menu("pasta", "Pasta", 2);

$menu[] = new Menu("spaghetti", "Spaghetti", 1.50);

$menu[] = new Menu("pizza", "Pizza", 5);

$menu[] = new Menu("chicken_wings_x4", "Chicken Wings X4", 4.50);

$menu[] = new Menu("cheeseburger", "Cheeseburger", 6);

$menu[] = new Menu("Sandwich", "Sandwich", 2);

$menu[] = new Menu("hamburger", "Hamburger", 4.50);

$menu[] = new Menu("stuff", "stuff", 15.50);

//FOR EACH ELEMENT CREATE A FORM
for($i=0; $i<count($menu); $i++){
  add_form($menu[$i]->form_name, $menu[$i]->name, $menu[$i]->price);
}


echo '</h1>';
echo '</div>'; //Close leftpane
...Do Others stuff in middlepane and in rightpane
```

To be clearer in html, for example the first form will be:

```
<input type="text" name="pasta" id="pasta" style="font-size:12pt;height:30px"/> x2€ price:X€<br>
```

I thought to divide in 3 parts my leftpane and to place `$name` to the left, the form to the middle and the price to the right. But the problem is that i create form in function, so I do not know how to do it. 
This is my css:

```
<style>
input[type=text] {
    width: 10%;
    margin: 7.5px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit].class1 {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit].class2 {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftpane {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.middlepane {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rightpane {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 19.5px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your output code would really benefit from some additional HTML structure with classes that allow you to control their layout in a consistent way with CSS. I would update the `add_form()` function:

```
function add_form($product,$name,$productp) {
  $productpt = "X";

  echo '<div class="form-wrap">';
  echo '<span class="form-name">' . $name . '</span>';
  echo '<input type="text" name="'. $product. '" id="'. $product. '"/> <span class="form-label">x'.$productp. '€</span> <span class="form-price">price:'.$productpt.'€</span>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Then with the output having more targetable HTML structure you can do this with CSS:

```css
.form-wrap input {
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 30px
}
.form-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.form-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap">
  <span class="form-name">Something</span>
  <input type="text" name="something" id="somethingId" />
  <span class="form-label">x1€</span>
  <span class="form-price">price:1€</span>
</div>
<div class="form-wrap">
  <span class="form-name">Another one</span>
  <input type="text" name="anotherone" id="somethingId2" />
  <span class="form-label">x2€</span>
  <span class="form-price">price:2€</span>
</div>
<div class="form-wrap">
  <span class="form-name">Number Three</span>
  <input type="text" name="thirdone" id="somethingId3" />
  <span class="form-label">x3€</span>
  <span class="form-price">price:3€</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With forms it works! But i still have problems with price  https://imgur.com/a/qM3PHZU  (price:x are not aligned)
If i remove the decimal numbers and make same char number it is aligned (https://imgur.com/OsKz5VC).
Can I align also price text?

Comment: Another thing, sorry if I still bother you, can i to wrap up when a word is too long like this https://imgur.com/BO60ETN (look "spagetti")
(if it has spaces, it change line: https://imgur.com/In2Kcag)

Comment: for too long words you may want to add an overflow rule or a word-wrap rule... look those up..For your first question, if all the elements have classes you can target each of them with different instructions, make sure there is a width enough to force the following elements to line up. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean i should use `width` in class label?

Comment: Target it with CSS based on class and give `width` in the CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a table. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Or you could wrap every section into a div-container and define its width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function add_form($product,$name,$productp)
{
         $productpt = "X";

         echo "<table><tr>";
         echo "<td width='20%'>" . $name . "</td>";
         echo "<td width='20%'><input type='text' name='". $product . "' id='" . $product . "' style='font-size:12pt;height:30px;' /></td>";
         echo "<td width='20%'>x" . $productp . "€</td>";
         echo "<td width='20%'>price:" . $productpt . "€</td>";
         echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this can be a solution but i got this: https://imgur.com/BKj8Xgn
Probably to make it work I should works on the sizing, but i think I will use the html structure, thanks anyway

Comment: Yes you can play with the sizing.